# Convert mysql LONGTEXT value to VARCHAR value?

Tags: mysql

I have a function that post on a users facebook wall.

One thing that I send to facebook is some text that I get from my mysql table that is set to LONGTEXT. If I have the table set as LONGTEXT then the text is not send to facebook, but if I set the table to VARCHAR then the text is send to facebook!

So how can I convert the LONGTEXT value that I get so it becomes like a VARCHAR value, before I send it to facebook?

I use the table in many other places so I just cant convert the table itself to VARCHAR, its to much work! I have to convert the output instead.

Any input appreciated thanks!

Comment: I think the question you should be asking is 'why varchar is being sent to FB while longtext is not'.

Comment: And I have, trust me, but I havent found an answer!

Comment: `$pdo->exec("SET NAMES utf8");` fixes null outputs from `json_encode`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In **mysql** you can do:

```
SELECT ID, CAST(YourLongText as char(255)) AS YourVarchar FROM some_table
```

Did you mean like that

Comment: I get the text value like <%=rs("thetext")%>, how do I convert that?

Comment: well you have a "mysql" tag for your question so thats the mysql related answer to your question... or did you mean something else..

Comment: Ok, didnt see all of it first.
Can I convert the output instead of changing the sql selection?

Comment: Ok, with you sql would it be right if I did:
SELECT ID, CAST(thetexttable as varchar(10000)) AS thetexttable FROM gallery ?
Why select ID?
Have to leave for a bit, will be back and test your answer. Thanks!

Comment: that was just an example, if you want to just select your text like :SELECT CAST(thetexttable as .......

Comment: Thanks a lot Sudhir!
Now it works to send the text to facebook! 
Great!

Answer (score 0):

use cast as in the post from @Sudhir or use the mysql function convert:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/charset-convert.html

Answer (score 0):

use the CONVERT or CAST functions: http://www.geeksengine.com/database/single-row-functions/conversion-functions.php

CONVERT(expr,type)
In this form, CONVERT takes a value in the form of expr and converts it to a value of type.

CAST(expr AS type)
Using CAST() function is the same as using CONVERT() function except that it uses keyword AS in between expr and type rather than a comma.