# Convert HTML text stored on mysql LONGTEXT field to a readeable value?

Tags: mysql, iis, asp-classic, iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2

I am migrating and old apliccation on ASP. On one page some HTML text is show from a LONGTEXT field from a MySQL database. On the new server only the text that become from this LONGTEXT field is not shown.

I tried to convert the LONGTEXT to CHAR as suggested here:

[Convert mysql LONGTEXT value to VARCHAR value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9531109/convert-mysql-longtext-value-to-varchar-value)

```
SELECT ID, CAST(YourLongText as char(255)) AS YourVarchar FROM some_table
```

It works but the text stored is longer that. I tried to use char(10000). The query works on SQL Manager for MySQL but when I use it on the web application it shows nothing (empty).

Maybe I missed a configuration on IIS. ¿Where should I look? ¿Is there a way to properly CAST the LONGTEXT?

The text stored on the LONGTEXT is like this:

```
<font style=font-family:Tahoma;font-size:12px>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>  <table>  <tbody><tr>   <td>   <font style=font-family:Tahoma;font-size:12px>1111111111</p>   </td>   <td>   <font style=font-family:Tahoma;font-size:12px>PERSON NAME</p>   </td>   <td>   <font style=font-family:Tahoma;font-size:12px>PERSON MIDDLE NAME</p>   </td>   <td>   <font style=font-family:Tahoma;font-size:12px>PERSON LASTNAME</p>   </td>  </tr> </tbody></table>
```

I am reading the field on .ASP like this:

```
sql = "SELECT ID, CAST(YourLongText as char(255)) AS YourVarchar FROM some_table"
set rs = db.execute(sql)

if not rs.eof then
'nothing
else
%>  
    <div align="justify"><span style="font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 12px"><%=rs("YourVarchar")%></span></div>
<%
end if
```

EDIT 1: The HTML has nothing wrong. I tried replacing the LONGTEXT with just the text 'Test' and is not showing up neither.

Comment: It's probably a problem with or misconfiguration of myodbc driver.

Comment: @Shadow Both servers have installed mysql odbc 5.1.6

Comment: Perhaps you should try to install a newer version.

Comment: You mean that the application can display the LONGTEXT field normally locally, but it cannot be published on iis? and you can use F12 to see if there is an error message.

Comment: where is the code to output the value of `rs("YourVarchar")`?

Comment: @user2316116 I forgot to change it. I already edited it.

Answer (score 1):

This issue was solved upgrading the MySQL Connector ODBC from 5.1.1 to 5.1.6 version.